# Change parameter in Karaboga's code of ABC algorithm

Tags: neural-networks, algorithm, training

I'm working on a problem and need to use Karaboga's code of the ABC algorithm but I have some questions...

Does this formula for calculating a parameter have to be changed:

```
{/v_{ij}=x_{ij}+\phi_{ij}(x_{kj}-x_{ij}) */}
```

A standard one or this what Karaboga see is better for algorithm.

The second is the same question for this formula of calculating fitness:

```
{fFitness(ind)=1./(fObjV(ind)+1)}
```

[Link to ABC algorithm coded using C programming language](https://sci2s.ugr.es/sites/default/files/files/TematicWebSites/EAMHCO/Software/ABC.C)